# Why don't colleges and departments teach social skills?

Tags: etiquette, coursework, soft-skills, social-skills

After all, to do research with a professor, a student has to have good social skills. So why not have classes that teach social etiquette and social skills? It seems that many courses in college are "book courses." Yet, when students graduate, what really matters is how they present themselves and their social skills.

Comment: A very simple answer to this question is resources. Who exactly is going to teach this course, and what resources are you going to reallocate it in order to offer it?

Moreover, who is qualified to offer such a course? (Or is it just a series of soft-skill workshops?)

Comment: Additionally, how does one demonstrate mastery of these skills?  Although there are some commonalities across disciplines, good social skills involve being adaptable to a plethora of personalities and groups with their own diverse norms.  Perhaps it is a skill that is best mastered through experience rather than structured lecturing.

Comment: Perhaps because basic etiquette and social skills are something to be learned before one pursues an advanced degree?

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I disagree. For me, as for many other nerds, scientific and technical skills were easier to learn than social ones. Saying 'hey, wait before learning adv. maths and do sth with your social skills' is both disrespectful and wasteful.

Comment: A lot of the so-called social skills can be learned through lectures on sales and customer relationship. At least it worked well for me.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal: I agree with you.  It is an assumption that such social skills are naturally learned as a part of the students' education.  This is not necessarily so... It's not that social skills are necessarily harder to learn, but that we develop a notion that they are less important than scientific knowledge.  Thus, we regard it as secondary to academic knowledge until the point when we start to become professionals.  Then, it's not just what you know, but who you know that will land you the tenure-track position.

Comment: @SylvainPeyronnet:  That's a really great idea!  Where do you get such a training?  I presume through side jobs in the service industry? Or in a business school?

Comment: @Piotr: All human beings need social skills and have manifold opportunities to learn and practice them throughout their lives.  Speaking of social skills: when responding directly to someone else, please don't make something up and put it in quotation marks.  As it happens, I am a mathematician and have been studying mathematics for most of my conscious life.  And, as a human being, I have been interacting with other human beings for my entire life: these things happen *at the same time*.  My point is that teaching "social etiquette and social skills" in the university is way too late.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: If it's too late to teach it in the university—and I agree that it probably is—then your question now becomes more perplexing. Again, who teaches this course, and when?

Comment: @aeismail: I think there are some things best learned outside of the context of classrooms and courses.  The social skills I have come from interacting with and learning from various people: parents, significant others, neighbors, friends, enemies, schoolyard bullies, colleagues, barbers, cab drivers, baristas....

Comment: Let me also say that, as an academic mathematician, I know that some students in STEM fields are not the most socially advanced or well-adjusted people around.  (But by the way most college students are callow and self-centered compared to their later, more fully adult selves.  It is a lifelong process!) The question is whether this is *problematic*.  I would say that in most cases I know of, it isn't: as a professor, I don't choose the coolest or even the least awkward students to work with.

Comment: There are some people who are so socially challenged as to make me not want to work with them: severe body odor, pathological dishonesty, psychopathy...these are all deal-breakers.  But come on: these problems are not going to be fixed by having students take the right courses, are they??

Comment: @Paul "through side jobs in the service industry": exactly, before I became part of the academy ;)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark I do agree that social skills are important (they certainly go well beyond social etiquette). Nonetheless, I don't agree with premise that the university is too late. I would have benefited, among many others (for me it is easier to learn maths "in the natural way", than to learn social skills). Excuse me for the quotation marks (however, your exact words are just above, so there is no place for confusion, what were your words on what was a hyperbole).

Comment: Not all things that you must learn can also be taught. Experience is often the best teacher.

Comment: @Piotr: I'm not saying that people's social development should be complete by the time they enter university.  (In fact, I said the opposite...) Definitely one learns a lot of social skills as a university student: it is, for most people, their first chance to build their own lives largely independent of parental supervision.  I'm saying that much social learning must, and does, take place well before the university level.  (And I am surprised to be saying this: it seems absolutely incontestable.)  I am also saying that social learning is not best accomplished through coursework.

Comment: @Piotr: Also, I am not a fan of the rhetorical device in which you take what someone says, modify it / make it significantly more extreme, and then condemn this modified position, e.g. by calling it "disrespectful and wasteful".  From a logical perspective you haven't added much -- you're condemning something that no one has said -- but there are some unpleasant insinuations which could get in the way of calm, friendly discourse.

Comment: I have to object to the premise of the question — _Yet, when students graduate, what really matters is how they present themselves and their social skills._  I have seen students with horrible social skills land good jobs, based entirely on their academic and research records.  I have also seen weak students passed over for good jobs despite impeccable people skills.  Yes, social skills are incredibly important, but characterizing them as "what really matters" is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @JeffE: indeed, if you have moderately below average social skills but are talented, competent and professional, then I think academia is a good career for you!  (Not you in particular, of course...)

Comment: @PeteL.Clark: Is it that obvious?  :-)  But I didn't mean only academic jobs.  The spectrum of social skills is just as varied in the Real World as it is in academia.

Comment: This question is perfect for this SE new site: [undergraduates](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/49571/teachers-school) if you find it useful you can follow it and help us in spreading the word about it.

Answer (score 3):

During one's university life as an undergraduate, there are many opportunities to improve one's social skills and confidence as an adult. These range from the various sporting and political clubs students can join, through volunteer activities students can participate in, through coaching activities (of more junior students or even high school), all the way to activities like having a few drinks in the uni bar (soda, for US students). During the summer, one can participate in *spring break*-style activities or get an internship at a law firm.

All of these activities, I dare say, help shape a student into a person. There's no assessment, no assignments, no grades, but such is the school of hard knocks.

Answer (score 3):

I heard that there where some (highly wanted) trials in Potsdam (maybe somewhere else):

- [Soft Skills Colloquium, Hasso Plattner Institut, Potsdam](http://www.hpi.uni-potsdam.de/studium/soft_skills/soft_skills_colloquium.html?L=1)
- [Computer geeks learn to flirt](http://www.reuters.com/article/2009/01/09/us-flirting-odd-idUSTRE5085DE20090109) (Reuters):

> Even the most quirky of computer nerds can learn to flirt with finesse thanks to a new "flirting course" being offered to budding IT engineers at Potsdam University south of Berlin.
>
> The 440 students enrolled in the master's degree course will learn how to write flirtatious text messages and emails, impress people at parties and cope with rejection.

To name the (alleged) reasons, why university courses in social skills are so rare:

- many social skills can't be easily fitted into a course scheme,
- there is a common belief (with which I strongly disagree) that there is no such need (as its to late (not necessary) or people will learn it automatically  (a wishful thinking)),
- there may be a huge difference in initial social skill levels (from one where no course is needed to one, when a course won't change things),
- teaching social skills may be difficult, as many things are very culturally- and context-dependent.

Personally, I regret that there were no social skills courses at my university (so I had to learn from books, mostly - undergraduate psychology). For me, as for many other STEM students, it was (relatively) easier to learn technical material "in the natural way", than social skills.

However, social skills (as any other skills), are the best to be honed in practice (at least after). There are many opportunities, e.g.:

- teamwork on any project (scientific or "just for fun"),
- running a students' chapter or club,
- organizing trips, excursions, movie nights, parties, ...,
- organizing a students' conference.

Answer (score 1):

At our university (the Netherlands) students are actively involved in group projects and as a part of the preparation to these projects they get some training on how to give talks, how to negotiate, how to organize/chair meetings, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the OP's question of why colleges don't teach social skills. Pointing out that yours does fails to answer the question of why the most others don't.

Comment: My only point was to show that not *all* colleges do not. The academic landscape is diverse enough also in this respect.

Comment: I would call these "professional skills" rather than "social skills", and I think it's a useful distinction to make.